# Any idea to make a particular document Print always in a printer which isn't default?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I print my wages document (Microsoft-Word 2000) always in a color printer, while all other documents (Word, Excel, etc..) in my default B&W printer. Is there any way I could make Color Printer as default only for that particular Document ?

Some application or a VBA macro?

Comment: Intrestign question... can't wait for the answer.

Comment: If memory serves, in Word you can write a VBA macro to intercept the print dialogue. Then you can call some print function and set the name of the printer in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

None of these "really" solve the issue which MPS (Managed Print Services) deliver for Windows (it uses a "virtual" printer then routes it through to the correct one depending on your criteria). There must be a way to specify this behaviour (colour on one printer, BW on another) like you can in CUPS.

1. Use a launcher batch script and this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php to set a default printer when the user clicks on an icon for a colour printer (you can even use a different file association to call your script before the MS Word document).
2. Use a VBA macro that overrides FilePrint and changes the ActivePrinter global variable.
3. Use fast-user switching. The default printer is per-user and by utilising "run-as" for certain application you can fool it into kind of working. So the user has 2x windows open (preferably with different "themes" one black for bw and one blue for colour) then they use the correct Word window for the correct type of document. If you create 2x icons on the desktop (Word B/W and Word Colour) it may be practical.
4. Use a CUPS server for printing (can be integrated with SAMBA).